# Call overridden method in parents constructor in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I have some code (C++11) like this:

Form.hpp:

```
class CForm{
public: 
     CForm(int paTemplate);
protected:
     virtual void createFromTemplate(int paTemplate);
}
```

Dialog.hpp

```
class CDialog : public CForm {
public:
    CDialog(int paTemplate);
private:
    void createFromTemplate(int paTemplate);
};
```

Form.cpp

```
CForm::CForm(int paTemplate){
    createFromTemplate(paTemplate);
}
```

Dialog.cpp

```
CDialog::CDialog(int paTemplate) : CForm(paTemplate){
    active = false;
}
```

I want my dialog to call it's own `createFromTemplate`, in this way the form's `createFromTemplate` is called. How can I achieve it? (I call `CDialog(template);` in my `main`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible - when you call virtual function in constructor/destructor, the version from "this" class or below is called. In your case, it would always call CForm::createFromTemplate(), no matter what you do.

Check this link - http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html - it's a chapter from "Effective C++".

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `CDialog` is not yet created (remeber class construction order: from top to bottom), so there is no override for the function `createFromTemplate`.

If you need the function to be virtual then I guess the best option is to add a new protected method in `CForm` (lets call it `initializeComponent`), which should be called from the constructor of `CDialog`

```
class CForm {
    // .. stuff

protected:
    virtual void createFromTemplate(int paTemplate);

    void initializeComponent() {
        createFromTemplate()
    }   
};

class CDialog: public CForm {
    CDialog(...) : CForm(...) {
        initializeComponent();
    }   
};
```

My 2 cents